# multidimensional array merge operation inside loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

let's say I have two arrays like so:

```
$array1 = array('A' => array(
        'B' => array(
            'C' => array(
                'D' => array(
                    'data' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'id' => 1,
                            'name' => 'name 1'),
                        1 => array(
                            'id' => 2,
                            'name' => 'name 2')))))));

$array2 = array('A' => array(
        'B' => array(
            'C' => array(
                'E' => array(
                    'data' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'id' => 3,
                            'name' => 'name 3'),
                        1 => array(
                            'id' => 4,
                            'name' => 'name 4')))))));
```

As you can see, the two arrays have the same key A, B, and C but the keys are different afterwards. How do I merge these two arrays into something like this:

```
$final_array = array('A' => array(
                'B' => array(
                    'C' => array(
                        'D' => array(
                            'data' => array(
                                0 => array(
                                    'id' => 1,
                                    'name' => 'name 1'),
                                1 => array(
                                    'id' => 2,
                                    'name' => 'name 2'))), 
                        'E' => array(
                            'data' => array(
                                0 => array(
                                    'id' => 3,
                                    'name' => 'name 3'),
                                1 => array(
                                    'id' => 4,
                                    'name' => 'name 4')))))));
```

As you can see, in this case I merge the arrays together into the same array that contains different keys for both. In order words, here I'm putting the array starting from key E from the second array into the array with index C.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

**EDIT:** Now, how about if my arrays ($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4, etc...) are generated inside a foreach loop, how do I merge all of those arrays together (Notice that I do not know the number of arrays beforehand)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

This should do the trick.

Added:

```
$collection=array();
foreach() {
     $collection[]=$myArray; //here you add your array to collection
} 
print_r(call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $collection));
```

Comment: Don't forget to tick my answer if you have no more questions. :) Glad to help.

Comment: actually I have another question (I knew my question was more challenging than that ;), See edit.

Comment: It works, but the only problem is that you are limiting $collection to 4 arrays, like I said, $collection could contain 10, or 15 or 20 arrays and those arrays are retrieved inside a foreach based on some condition. Anyway, it's easy to modify it now to get what I want, thanks again a million times man

Comment: Think again. If your arrays are generated in foreach loop, you can store them in $collection. Updated.

Comment: Almost 9 years later this answer saves me.

Answer (score -1):

i have not tested this but try this code:

```
foreach( $array1 as $key => $val )
{
 if( !in_array( $key, $array2 ) )
 {
  $array2[$key] = $val;
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

use Rok Kralj's answer, using native functions are probably the best way to do this as they are much faster.

Comment: please explain the reason for down voting?